# Inheritance not working when implementing method in C++

Tags: c++

I have 2 files I am working on: `encoder.h` and `encoder.cc`.

As far as I know the inherited methods (initialize and read) should be available in the `MotorEncoder` class. However when I try to implement the methods the compiler throws an error. Any ideas?

Header

```
class Encoder {
protected:
    u32 bitResolution;
    SPI spi;

public:
    void initialize(u16 spiDeviceID, u32 bitResolution);
    u32 read();
};

class MotorEncoder : public Encoder {
public:
// If I comment these 2 lines it SHOULD work as far as I know, 
// but it won't compile due to the method not being defined when 
// implementing e.g. in MotorEncoder::initialize()
void initialize(u16 spiDeviceID, u32 bitResolution);
u32 read();
};
```

Implementation

```
void Encoder::initialize(u16 spiDeviceID, u32 bitResolution) {
    // ....
}

u32 Encoder::read() {
    //
}


void MotorEncoder::initialize(u16 spiDeviceID, u32 bitResolution) {
    // implementation
}

u32 MotorEncoder::read() {
    // implementation code
}
```

Comment: You probably need to declare `initialize` and `read` as `virtual` in `class Encoder`

Comment: `initialize`- and `read`- methods should be `virtual` in base class.

Comment: In C/C++ langauge, the default binding is static/compile-time. You will need to specify runtime-binding of member-function, using `virtual` keyword. The base and derived function signature must match.

Comment: @Ajay: _should_ match - it's technically not an error if they are different. You just get two unrelated functions as a result. That's why there's `override` - that will turn a signature mistake in the derived class into an error. Always use it when deriving from a base class from a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your methods in base and derived classes currently are unrelated. They just happen to have the same name.

The complete call expression would be `this->Encoder::read()` and `this->MotorEncoder::read()`. You may leave out `this->`, and unqualified `read()` would refer to `MotorEncoder::read()`, but they're still two functions.

That said, I think you have a more fundamental misunderstanding of inheritance. You don't need to declare or define `MotorEncoder::read`, precisely because it's already inherited. You may also want to read up on `virtual`.

`initialize` is another worrying sign. In C++, initialization is done by constructors.

Comment: What we want to do is simply override the read and initialize methods of the base class. So that's why the two lines declaring these methods in MotorEncoder should not be there; it should be enough to override them in the `cc` file. 

(We are writing code later to be used on an FPGA, which is why dynamic allocation will not be supported and we are not using constructors.)

Comment: @Ortix92: _"it should be enough to override them in the cc file"_ Where did you hear that?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet the fields are inherited without redeclaration so why do we need to redeclare the methods? They should exist in the child class, am I correct? And I should be able to declare them as an override in the implementation, or not? I just don't understand why I have to redeclare the exact same method in the class if I'm inheriting these methods.

Comment: @Ortix92: No. The base class member functions are "inherited" but you can't define them twice. To create an override, you must first declare the override. It's not "the exact same method". `Base::foo()` is a different function from `Derived::foo()`, even though the latter overrides the former. And if you don't need an override then you just use `Base::foo()` throughout.

Comment: @Ortix92: That's my best guess on this issue : Imagine you are building a library. The only things your users see are your header files. Then, if you don't redeclare your derived functions in your header files, the users have no way to know in advance that you derived your function. He would only know at runtime, which is awfull. That's why the laguage imposes to redeclare the derived functions in the header files of the derived classes.

Comment: @MSalters It might be useful to add a note regarding vtables and how inheritance work in C++ in order to explain why the functions have to be declared virtual in the base class.

Comment: @ThomasBenard: That first comment makes no sense. For `virtual` functions, the library user doesn't even need to know derived classes _exist_ ! Let alone which members they have.

Comment: @MSalters I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If I have a class `Shape` with a `rotate()` virtual function and also a class `Circle` that derives from `Shape` and overrides `rotate()`. If the language lets me do so without redeclaring `rotate()` in `Circle`, then its users have no way to know that I did before runtime.

Comment: @ThomasBenard: My opoint is that the users may now even _know_ that you have a `class Circle` ! You may have a function `std::shared_ptr<Shape> makeEllipse(float a, float b)` that returns a `Circle` if `a==b`.